# Is it random and representative of all Australians if 200 people are interviewed from the the Sydney area Phone book?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, survey-sampling

1000 people selected, 200 replies those were taken in as data. Is this representative of Australian even though it's just in the sydney area. Is it random?

Comment: Were the 1k people selected from all Australians, w/ each having an equal probability of selection?

Comment: *Of course* it's not representative of Australia if it's just from Sydney!  The data you have, according to your description, might--at best--be representative of people in the Sydney area with telephone numbers who respond to surveys.

Comment: whuber's comment should definitely be the correct answer.

Comment: Another thing to consider: these days you have a lot of people who don't have a landline, instead relying solely on their mobile phone. These people won't show up in the phone book at all.

Comment: This sounds like a routine textbook question. Is this from some subject?